# Why can't I get data by xpath with HtmlAgilityPack?

Tags: c#, html, .net, xpath, html-agility-pack

I'm experimenting with twitch chat-**scraper** type program, but i can't seem to get any data from chat, live or recorded. I'm guessing is because of messages are behind JavaScript code.

First I tried traditional method, using xpath, but it returns null

```
 public void jel()
    {
        string Url = "https://www.twitch.tv/swordys/chat?popout=";
        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(Url);

        string chat_m = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id=\"ember945\"]/span[6]")[0].InnerText;
        Console.WriteLine(chat_m);
    }
```

Then with FireFox's "FirePath" plugin, but it still gives me same result

```
public void jel()
    {
        string Url = "https://www.twitch.tv/swordys/chat?popout=";
        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(Url);

        string chat_m = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("html//body//div//div//div//div//div//div//div//div//ul//li//span//")[0].InnerText;
        Console.WriteLine(chat_m);
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please paste your code into the question instead of attaching images of it

Comment: Just added, thanks for correction.

Comment: So, what kinds of HTML elements did you want to select? And once that is answered, do you expect those elements to be present immediately when the page is delivered, or only after some chatting has occurred (i.e. after Javascript has been running)? When I go to that URL, there is no element with the id `ember945`, so it's not surprising that your first XPath expression doesn't select anything. But I don't really know what you're trying to select.

Comment: Want to select Html's inner text. (twitch chat messages). Yes after chatting, or in live chat situations, or even recorded chat on some streams. Can't seem to get any of them using xpath, my code was example of message that i typed on my twitch chat. I apologize if i'm not cooperating correctly, fairly new to webscraping.